# how to fetch record of child in parent class in google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo

i am working in one Gwt project and in Back-end using Google app engine. my requirement is to fetch record of child table from parent class in Google app engine.
i have two server side Persistent class 
1) Fruit
2) Apple

Fruit class is like this

@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, table = "fruit")
public class Fruit implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 2523048232286090409L;

public Fruit() {}

@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
private Long id;


@Column(name="apple_id")
@Persistent(column="id")
private Apple apple;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Apple getApple() {
    return apple;
}

public void setApple(Apple apple) {
    this.apple = apple;
}
```

}

class Apple is like this

@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, table = "apple")
public class Apple {

```
@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Persistent
private String colour;

public Apple() {}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getColour(){
    return this.colour;
}

public String setColour(String colour){
    this.colour = colour;
}
```

}

now i want name of colour by querying on fruit.

in daoImpl class i have build method for fetching data

```
fetchFruit(){

    Query query = pm.newQuery(Fruit.class);
    List<Fruit> list=null;
    try{        
        list = (List<Fruit>) query.execute();

    }finally{
        pm.close();
    }
}
```

in my serviceImpl class i have done like this

private static FruitDAO fruitDAO = new FruitDAO();

```
    List<Fruit> fruitObj = fruitDAO.fetchFruit();


 for(Fruit fruit : fruitObj){
            FruitDTO dto = new fruitDTO();

            dto.setId(fruit.getId());               
            dto.setAppple(fruit.getApple());
    }
```

i get null on fruit.getApple()

my question is am I going right way if not then how it is possible ?
how can I get name of colour by querying on fruit.
any other way to querying on fruit ?

please help me.
thank in advance.

Comment: Why does Fruit have a relation to Apple ? It should be the superclass of it.

Comment: DataNucleus i have to fetch record of child class querying from parent class. consider another scenario User and UserProfile in User class i have object of UserProfile and i have to fetch UserProfile data from User class.

Comment: Indeed, but you haven't done the first step in debugging, look at the log at when you get the "Fruit", and its "lifecycle state"